# javafx with iframe and webviewer

Tags: java, css, iframe, javafx, webview

I'm making a program which asks the user for a search term. The program then looks for relevant links and merges them together (amount to be merged is user specified)
It then displays the merged results in a javafx webviewer scene.

I'm using the following code to merge the links

```
htmlCode = htmlCode + ("<iframe src =" + url + "width=\"800\" "+" height=\"600\""  + "></iframe><br>") ;
```

which generates the following code (note `<html>` head etc excluded)

```
<iframe src =http://stackoverflow.com/questionswidth="800"  height="600">  </iframe><br>
<iframe src =http://stackoverflow.com/%3Ftab%3Dfeaturedwidth="800"  height="600"></iframe><br>
<iframe src =http://stackoverflow.com/%3Ftab%3Dhotwidth="800"  height="600">
```

But in the stage where the results are displayed they only take up half of the space regardless of how many pixels I set the width to.

I'm confident it's not a problem with the stage as it was filling the whole width of the stage but the height was to small so I added the code to change the height (which worked).
Any ideas?

Comment: <iframe src =http://stackoverflow.com/%3Ftab%3Dhot width="800"  height="600">

Comment: htmlCode = htmlCode + ("<iframe src =" + url + " width=\"800\" "+" height=\"600\""  + "></iframe><br>") ;

question solved there was no space between the end of the url and the width